# Solving the Euler equation $t^2 \ddot{x} + 3t \dot x + x = \frac{2}{t}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the Euler equation 
$$ t^2 \ddot{x} + 3t \dot x  + x = \frac{2}{t}.$$
Using new coorinates $y=x$ and $s= \log(t)$ transforms the quation into the form
$$ \text{e}^{2s} \ddot{y} + 3\text{e}^{s}  \dot y  + y = 2\text{e}^{-s} \Longleftrightarrow  \text{e}^{3s} \ddot{y} + 3\text{e}^{2s}  \dot y  + y = 2.$$
How can I continue to solve this equation?

Answer (score 3):

First, try the homogeneous piece:

$$t^2 \ddot{x} + 3 t \dot{x} + x=0$$

Note that the power of the coefficient minus the order of the derivative is fixed at zero (e.g., 2-2, 1-1, 0-0).  This demands a solution of the form $x(t) = t^a$, where we now may find $a$:

$$a (a-1) + 3 a + 1=0 \implies a^2+2 a+1 = 0$$

or $a=-1$ as a double root.  In this case, the general solution is

$$x(t) = \frac{A}{t} + B \frac{\log{t}}{t}$$

This is completely analogous to the constant coefficient case in which a double root produces a solution like $t e^{a t}$.  In fact, it is the same thing.  Thus, in an analogous fashion, I am going to assume the particular solution has the form

$$x(t) = C \frac{\log^2{t}}{t} $$

Plugging this into the above equation, you will find that $C=1$.  Thus, the general solution of the above equation is

$$x(t) = \frac{A}{t} + B \frac{\log{t}}{t} + \frac{\log^2{t}}{t}$$